# How to access .dev file via bash script

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, kernel

Below is a `device.dev` file that contains some configuration info for a specific application called ads2.

```
1 DEVICES {
2        GLOBAL-CONFIG {
3            framerate = "20000";
4            subframes = "0";
5            max_consec_timeouts = "10";
6            max_total_timeouts = "1000";
7            schedmode = "Standard";
8        }
9        IO-DEVICES {
10        }
11        COMPUTING-DEVICES {
12            RT_WORKSTATION x-NB-0144 = {
13                hostname = "x-x-0144";
14                ipaddress = "xxx.x.x.xx";
15                DISPLAYS {
16                    main = "FDT-C-VM-0094:0.0";
17                }
18                SCHEDPARAM {
19                    active = "0";
20                    framerate = "20000";
21                    subframes = "0";
22                    max_consec_timeouts = "10";
23                    max_total_timeouts = "1000";
24                }
25            }
27  
28            RT_HOST xxx-c-agx-vw-89 = { 
29                hostname = "xxxxx@xxxx-desktop";
30                ipaddress = "xx.xx.xx.xx";         
31                SCHEDPARAM {
32                    active = "0";
33                    framerate = "20000";
34                    subframes = "0";
35                    max_consec_timeouts = "10";
36                   max_total_timeouts = "1000";
37                }
38            }
39        }
40    }
```

I'm trying to write a bash script that accepts an input which is an IP-address and then access the `device.dev` file and pass it to the variable `ipaddress` in line 30.

So is it possible to access devices.dev file via bash script?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "So is it possible to access devices.dev file via bash script?" - Yes, this is possible. What have you tried? What is your question?

Comment: @Tsyvarev. the question is how since I already tried ex. sed on .txt and it worked, however it didn't on .dev file. But i will try the answer by Pierluigu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU awk and focusing on the second entry only:

```
awk -v ipadd="1.1.1.1" '/ipaddress/ { cnt++ } /ipaddress/ && cnt==2 { lne=gensub(/(^.*\")(.*)(\".*$)/,"\\1"ipadd"\\3",$0);print lne;next }1' devices.dev > devices.tmp && mv -f devices.tmp devices.dev
```

Explanation:

```
awk -v ipadd="1.1.1.1" '/ipaddress/ {                                          # Pass the ip address to change to as a variable ipadd to awk
            cnt++                                                              # Where there is ipaddress in the line, increment a cnt variable
         } 
/ipaddress/ && cnt==2 {                                                        # Where there is ipaddress in the line and cnt is 2, process
            lne=gensub(/(^.*\")(.*)(\".*$)/,"\\1"ipadd"\\3",$0);               # Set a variable lne to an entry that substitutes the existing IP address for the one passed in ipadd using awk's gensub function
            print lne;                                                         # Print the amendment
            next                                                               # Skip to the next line
         }1' devices.dev > devices.tmp && mv -f devices.tmp devices.dev        # Print all none amended lines and redirect the output to a temp file (devices.tmp) before over writing the devices.dev file with the temp file
```

Comment: This what i get `mv: cannot stat ‘devices.tmp’: No such file or directory`. Besides, the devices.dev file is located at `c:\Techsat\ADS2\config\devices.dev`

Comment: There was a "typo" on the tmp file name. Try it now.

Comment: Thanks man. You're really a gold mine. However, the file must only be located in  `c:\Techsat\ADS2\config\devices.dev`. So can I simply refer to it by just writng the path instead of `devices.dev`?

Comment: It turns out its straight forward and works, just passed the path to the file. Thanks

Comment: Would be honored if i could et your contact on linkdn.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to replace value exactly at line 30, you can create this file sed.sh in the same dir of device.dev

```
#!/bin/bash
IP=$1
sed -i "30s/ipaddress.*/ipaddress = \"$IP\"/" device.dev
```

and execute with

```
bash sed.sh 1.2.3.4
```

device.dev will have 1.2.3.4 at line 30

Comment: Thanks for the answer, What if the file is located in certain directory?

Comment: And the ip-adress at line 30 in which i want to set through user-input could not be located at line 30. the variable ip-adress is mentioned two times and the one to be replaced is always the second

Comment: if the file is located in another directory just hardcode the path to device.dev inside the script (you can also parametrize with $2 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/298706/how-to-pass-parameters-to-function-in-a-bash-script)

Comment: if the line you want to replace is always after a certain line, I think the simpler method is to specify a range in which replace apply.
Try modifying the sed command with different options, like:
sed -i "20,1000s/ipaddress.*/ipaddress = \"$IP\"/"" device.dev
will apply from 20th to 1000th line