# Bash script how to display matched words in custom order

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, cut

The following is the output of the command `ads2 cls create`

```
kernel with pid 7148 (port 9011) killed
kernel with pid 9360 (port 9011) killed
probing service daemon @ http://fdt-c-vm-0093.fdtech.intern:9010
starting kernel FDT-C-VM-0093 @ http://fdt-c-yy-0093.ssbt.intern:9011 name=FDT-C-VM-0093 max_consec_timeouts=10 clustermode=Standard hostname=FDT-C-VM-0093 framerate=20000 schedmode=Standard rtaddr=fdt-c-vm-0093.fdtech.ssbt tickrole=Local tickmaster=local max_total_timeouts=1000
kernel FDT-C-VM-0093 running
probing service daemon @ http://172.16.xx.xx:9010
starting kernel FDT-C-AGX-0004 @ http://172.16.xx.xx:9011 name=FDT-C-AGX-0004 max_consec_timeouts=10 clustermode=Standard hostname=FDT-C-AGX-0004 framerate=20000 schedmode=Standard rtaddr=172.16.xx.xx tickrole=Local tickmaster=local max_total_timeouts=1000
kernel Fxx-x-xxx-xxx4 running
>>> start cluster establish ...
>>> cluster established ...
        nodes {
            node {
                name = "FDT-C-VM-xxxx";
                address = "http://fxx-x-xx-0093.xxx.intern:xxxx/";
                state = "3";
            }
            node {
                name = "xxx-x-xxx-xxx";
                address = "http://1xx.16.xx.xx:9011/";
                state = "3";
            }
        }
```

However, I'm trying to extract the value of `name` and `state` for each node, save them in a variable  and display them in the following order:

```
**#example output**

Node fdt-c-agx-xxx has state 3
Node FDT-C-VM-xxx has state 3
```

Till now i, with the help of this so much powerful learning site, could extract the values of `name` and `state` by executing the following:

```
cls="$(ads2 cls create | grep '\(state\|name\) =' | cut -d '"' -f 2)"
```

Now if i print `cls` variable, i get the following:

```
FDT-C-VM-xxx
3
FDT-C-AGX-xxx
3
```

**First Question:**

How can i display the result like the one above in the `**#example output**`?

**Second question**

With this implementation, how can I check the value of `state` varaiable for both nodes in order to print something like

```
if node1State = 3 && node2State = 3; then
echo "Sucess"
else 
echo "Failed"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the output seems to be json, you should really use a json parser such as jq but in the absence of jq you can use awk and combine the requirements for question one and two:

```
ads2 cls create | awk -F [\"] '/^>>> cluster established .../ { strt=1 } strt!=1 { next } $1 ~ "name" { cnt++;nam[cnt]=$2 } $1 ~ "state" { stat[cnt]=$2;print "Node "nam[cnt]" has state "$2 } END { if (stat[1]=="3" && stat[2]=="3") { print "Success" } else { print "Failed" } }'
```

Explanation:

```
 ads2 cls create | awk -F [\"] '                                         # Set the field delimiter to a double quote
/^>>> cluster established .../ { 
               strt=1                                                    # If the line starts with ">>> cluster established ...", set a variable strt to 1
            }
 strt!=1    { 
               next                                                      # If strt is not equal to 1, skip to the next line
            }
 $1 ~ "name" { 
               cnt++;                                                    # If the first field contains name, increment a cnt variable
               nam[cnt]=$2                                               # Use the cnt variable as the index of an array called nam with the second field the value
             }  
 $1 ~ "state" {   
               stat[cnt]=$2;                                             # When the first field contains "state", set up another array called stat
               print "Node "nam[cnt]" has state "$2                      # Print the node name as well as the state
               } 
           END { 
                 if (stat[1]=="3" && stat[2]=="3") { 
                   print "Success"                                       # At the end of processing, use the array to determine whether there is a success of failure.
                 } 
                 else { 
                   print "Failed" 
                 } 
                }'
```

Comment: thanks alot. This works, however it returns Failed and it must return Success

Comment: With the output posted, it returns Success.

Comment: I've updated the question showing the full output. I hope you don't mind

Comment: OK, I've amended to ensure that processing only occurs after "cluster established" line

Comment: Thanks man you're realy awesome. Could you suggest a helpful learning site?

Comment: Woud be glad if you could help me with this one:). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66752884/how-to-access-dev-file-via-bash-script?noredirect=1#comment118001125_66752884

Comment: I'd suggest you keep checking this site as there as some good solutions posted. If my answer fits your needs, please take the time to accept it as an answer.

Comment: i just have one question. `In echo -e " "` i can print the text in colors ,. However, how can this be done with print command like the case here? such that i print `Success` as green

Comment: Hi again, i hope you can still respond. when i execute your solution, i get `0Node fdt-c-agx-0008 has state 3
0Node FDT-NB-0144 has state 3`. How can i get rid of the zeros at the beginning, and is it possible to display both numbers `3` with `green` color?